# Обособление оборота "в первую очередь"

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

**В первую очередь, вы должны любить математику, потому что программирование очень тесно с ней связано.**

*Нужно ли обособлять "в первую очередь"?*
Нашёл в интернете правило: если легко подобрать синонимы "вначале", "наперво" и другие, то не обособляется. Если же выражение "в первую очередь" выступает в качестве вводного оборота, и оно близко по смыслу к обороту "прежде всего", то обособляется.

Здесь, как я вижу, легко заменить оборот с помощью "прежде всего", поэтому считаю, что обособлять нужно. Прав ли я?

Answer (score 2):

**В первую очередь вы должны любить математику, потому что программирование очень тесно с ней связано.** Смысл такой: главное и основное  ― вы должны любить математику.

В справочнике "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации" предлагается **не обособлять наречный оборот**, хотя допускается обособление в некоторых случаях: 
Необходимо **в первую очередь** учитывать, что ситуация, которая сложилась к настоящему моменту в России, долго существовать не может. [Виктор Пелевин. Generation «П» (1999)].

При обособлении меняется оттенок смысла: **В первую очередь (во-первых), вы должны любить математику.** Смысл такой: не любить математику нельзя, но об особом отношении к ней не говорится.

Comment: Sibylla, то есть правильно ли я понимаю, что для разграничения, когда нужно обособлять этот оборот, а когда нет, можно использовать следующую вещь: если можно заменить "главное и основное" вместо "в первую очередь", то не обособляется, а если "во-первых" -- то нужна запятая? Понял ли я Вас правильно?

Comment: *В первую очередь (во-первых), вы должны любить математику.*  Заменять нельзя, вернее, это не аргумент. "Во-первых" обособляется. "В первую очередь" – нет. К тому же, @Sibylla, вы не привели примера с обособлением, хотя справочник, по вашим словам, допускает его "в некоторых случаях".

Comment: @Niemand Из справочника: Бабийчук, при всех своих положительных качествах, был прижимист, всегда имел запас курева, знал, как о себе лично позаботиться, и, заботясь о других, тем самым, в первую очередь, заботился о себе (Юрий Герман).

Comment: @vjg Замена не всегда помогает решить такие задачи. Семантика вводного слова и наречия в данном случае трудно различаются, приходится анализировать их грамматическую функцию. При обособлении в качестве вводного слова мы как бы составляем перечень по пунктам, а без обособления наречие напрямую относится к глаголу, подчеркивая его значимость.   Поэтому лучше не обособлять это выражение, как предлагает справочник. У Германа тоже "прежде всего" скорее наречие, обособление связано с позицией сочетания и его добавочным значением.

Comment: @Sibylla, ну явно же полная фигня, сплошной спотыкач. Сто вводных, уточнений и пояснений в одной фразе, и рука уже по инерции ставит и ставит эти бесконечные запятые, не в силах остановиться. Даже у классиков не каждая запятая гениальна. Две последние не нужны.

Comment: Запятые факультативны,  но я ничего не имею против их постановки.  Герман (с точки зрения интонации) отправляет сочетание на второй план, оно так удобнее читается. Я бы только после "прижимист" поставила бы двоеточие: так меньше запятых и раскрытие темы обозначено.

Answer (score 0):

> Здесь, как я вижу, легко заменить оборот с помощью "прежде всего",
>   поэтому считаю, что обособлять нужно. Прав ли я?

Да, здесь именно так. Это правило (лучше сказать: "пунктограмма", запоминалка) на самом деле всего лишь помогает отличить значение "сделать раньше" от "считать главным". Здесь, очевидно, речь идёт о чем-то главном, а не о том, что надо сделать раньше по времени (хотя и это не исключено). В таком случае нужно обособление.

Answer (score 0):

Грамота весьма категорична:

> В ПЕРВУЮ ОЧЕРЕДЬ, наречное выражение. Не требует постановки знаков препинания. (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_101).

Я, однако, считаю, что выражение В ПЕРВУЮ ОЧЕРЕДЬ может быступать и как вводное (подобно *во-первых*), и в этом случае должно отделятья запятой.

Вариант с запятой.
*В первую очередь, вы должны любить математику* (Во-первых, вы должны любить математику; в первую очередь я хочу сказать, что вы должны любить математику.)

Вариант без запятой. *В первую очередь вы должны любить математику* (Вы должны любить математику — это самое первое и самое главное для вас.)