# Обособление оборота "в первую очередь" в середине предложения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, наречия

Пожалуйста, объясните, нужна ли тут запятая?
В справочнике сайта *Грамота.ру* чётко сказано, что запятыми "в первую очередь" не обособляется. Однако на других сайтах написано, что выделять запятыми его можно. Получается, что это зависит лишь от того значения, которое я вкладываю в предложение? Есть другие наречные выражения, с которыми возможна такая двоякость? Играет ли роль то, в какой части предложения оно находится?

[**В ПЕРВУЮ ОЧЕРЕДЬ,** наречное выражение](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_101)

**Этим префиксом Тошка отмечает интересные(,) в первую очередь(,) для себя темы.**

P.S. Я видел [другой вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432451/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C) про это же наречное выражение, но до конца всё же не понимаю.

Comment: Откройте справочник Фрамполь по вводным словам. Там все подробно написано (и про другие наречные выражения тоже). Есть такое наречие "сначала". Оно не отделяется запятыми. Если по смыслу возможна замена "в первую очередь" на "сначала", то запятыми не отделяем: "В первую очередь нужно говорить именно 
об этом; "

Comment: @user190920, а что за справочник? В Интернете есть?

Comment: Наберите в гугле "справочник Фрамполь скачать". Первая же ссылка https://lib.agu.site/books/125/1386/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
```

Сочетание в первую очередь, как правило, не требует постановки знаков препинания. Однако в некоторых контекстах, где слова в первую очередь сближаются по смыслу с вводными словами «во-первых, прежде всего», обособление возможно. Решение о постановке запятых в этом случае принимает автор текста.

Что касается других наречных выражений, выступающих в роли вводных. Вот некоторые из них.

В свою очередь  не обособляется, если употребляется как наречное выражение в значении **«со своей стороны, в ответ, когда наступила очередь»:**

*Ася вопросительно посмотрела на меня. Я в свою очередь протянул ей руку и на этот раз крепко пожал ее холодные пальчики. И. Тургенев, Ася.*

Вводное, если указывают на то, что данное высказывание связано по смыслу с предшествующим:

Черное кольцо, **в свою очередь,** было опоясано золотисто-желтым кольцом, за ним следовало еще более широкое кольцо – зеленое, и, наконец, снаружи было еще одно, самое огромное, – черное кольцо. Н. Носов, Незнайка в Солнечном городе.
Слово наконец является вводным, если стоит в перечислительном ряду (часто с вводными словами во-первых, во-вторых и т. д. ), и является наречием, если по значению равно наречному выражению в конце концов:

Я вышел **наконец** к просеке — наречие.

Во-первых, я болен, во-вторых, устал **и, наконец,** просто не хочу идти туда — вводное слово.

О вводных словах можете прочитать здесь. [Грамма.ру](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.36)